# how to input image for class's prediction in keras using python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am trying to predict the result for a single image but it is giving an irrelevant result. I have trained the model on cifar 10 dataset
I have used keras and tensorflow to train this model. I suppose the input which I am providing is not of the correct size.

here is the gist of training code :https://github.com/09rohanchopra/cifar10/blob/master/cifar10-simple-cnn.ipynb
Code for predicting simgle image

#

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import load_model
from scipy.misc import imread,imresize
import numpy as np
model=load_model('augmented_best_model.h5')
im=imread('1.jpg')
im=im/255
im=im.resize(im,(32,32))
pr=model.predict(im.reshape(-1,3,32,32))
```

Comment: Why you've reshaped the image to channel first? In your training code the image input shape is `input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,CHANNELS)`

Comment: Also, if im has dtype of an integer, `im/255` will probably zero it in Python 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

```
x=imread('test/2.jpg',mode='RGB')
x=imresize(x,(32,32))
x=np.invert(x)
x=x.reshape(-1,32,32,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

imread is now deprecated. Better alternative is to use keras functions.

```
x = image.load_img('test/2.jpg', target_size=(32,32))
x = image.img_to_array(x)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
x = x/255.
```